# Attach invoice pdf to custom e-mail in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, invoice, attachment

I created a custom email and it's working fine like this:

```
    $data['amount'] = round($amount);
    $data['customer_name'] = $customer->getFirstname() . ' ' . $customer->getLastname();
    $data['customer_telephone'] = $customer->getMainTelephone();
    $data['customer_email'] = $customer->getEmail();
    $data['customer_credit_balance'] = round($creditBalance);
    $data['requested_at'] = $model->getRequestedAt();
    $data['customer_bank_account'] = $description;
    $storeName = $this->getStoreName();
    $storeEmail = $this->getStoreEmail();
    $senderInfo = [
        'name' => $storeName,
        'email' => $storeEmail
    ];
    $receiverInfo = [
          'name' => $data['customer_name'],
          'email' => $data['customer_email']
    ];
    $invoiceId = 5;
    $this->emailHelper->sendMail(
        $data,
        $senderInfo,
        $receiverInfo,
        'approve',
        $invoiceId
    );
```

email helper:

```
namespace Test\Xxxx\Helper;

class Email extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD_REQUEST  = 'test/xxxx/request_mail';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD_APPROVE  = 'test/xxxx/approve_mail';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD_REJECT  = 'test/xxxx/reject_mail';
    /* Here section and group refer to name of section and group where you create this field in configuration*/

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var string
    */
    protected $temp_id;

    /**
    * @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    * @param Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    * @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    * @param Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
    * @param Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $context;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Return store configuration value of your template field that which id you set for template
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getConfigValue($path, $storeId)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        );
    }

    /**
     * Return store
     *
     * @return Store
     */
    public function getStore()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore();
    }

    /**
     * Return template id according to store
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTemplateId($xmlPath)
    {
        return $this->getConfigValue($xmlPath, $this->getStore()->getStoreId());
    }

    /**
     * [generateTemplate description]  with template file and tempaltes variables values
     * @param  Mixed $emailTemplateVariables
     * @param  Mixed $senderInfo
     * @param  Mixed $receiverInfo
     * @return void
     */
    public function generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo)
    {
        $template =  $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->temp_id)
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, /* here you can defile area and
                                                                                 store of template for which you prepare it */
                        'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables)
                ->setFrom($senderInfo)
                ->addTo($receiverInfo['email'],$receiverInfo['name']);
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * [sendInvoicedOrderEmail description]
     * @param  Mixed $emailTemplateVariables
     * @param  Mixed $senderInfo
     * @param  Mixed $receiverInfo
     * @return void
     */
    /* your send mail method*/
    public function sendMail($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo,$type,$invoiceId = null)
    {
        if ($type == 'request') {
          $typeId = self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD_REQUEST;

        } elseif ($type == 'approve') {
          $typeId = self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD_APPROVE;
          if (!empty($invoiceId)) {
            $this->attachInvoicePdf($invoiceId);
          }
        } else{
          $typeId = self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD_REJECT;
        }
        $this->temp_id = $this->getTemplateId($typeId);
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $this->generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo);
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
    }

    public function attachInvoicePdf($invoiceId){
      // ???? how
    }

}
```

template:

```
 <!--@subject Your Request is Approved @-->
<!--@vars
{"htmlescape var=$name":"Recipient Name",
"htmlescape var=$sendername":"Sender name",
"var code":"Gift Card Code",
"var balance":"Gift Card Balance",
"var status":"Status",
"htmlescape var=$message":"Message",
"var expiredat":"Expired At"}
@-->

<!--@styles
body,td { background:#FFFFFF; margin:0; padding:0; color:#2f2f2f; font:13px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
pre{ white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; white-space: -o-pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;}
@-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<div style="font:13px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="98%"
           style="margin-top:10px; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-bottom:10px;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
                <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="660">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <p>
                                <strong>Dear {{var customer_name}},</strong>,<br/>
                                Your request to process {{var amount}} has been approved and processed.</br> 
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

if i have invoice id as a variable, how can i attach my pdf invoice to this email?

Comment: can you please provide the complete emailHelper class so we can see how you build the mail message object etc.

Comment: @HelgeB see my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `createAttachement` of `Zend_Mail` class. Your message should inherit this class. If you get the message from your transport class and add the attachement there it should work.

I would propose the following code - the creation of the invoice pdf is tested and safe, the rest is theoretical :-). Of course it might be usefull to transfer the object creation into constructor and add some error handling.

```
public function sendMail($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo,$type,$invoiceId = null)
{
    [...]
    $this->generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo);
    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
    //attach the invoice pdf
    $this->attachInvoicePdf($invoiceId);
    $transport->sendMessage();
    $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
}

private function attachInvoicePdf($invoiceId){

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $pdfInvoiceModel = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice');
    $invoice = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice')->load($invoiceId);
    $pdfContent = $pdfInvoiceModel->getPdf([$invoice])->render();
    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
    $transport->getMessage()->createAttachment($pdfContent);

}
```